# When does MSIGetProperty() API return nothing in its third parameter?

Tags: installshield

I am trying to query the CLIENTPROCESSID of the msiexec.exe process using the MSIGetProperty() API. The third parameter of this API should get the value of the property being passed as per Microsoft Docs. After calling,his API returns 0, which I think means ERROR_SUCCESS. However there is blank value or nothing within the szValueBuf parameter.

I have followed the exact method of getting the value as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msigetpropertya. I tried going through various Microsoft Docs but was not able to get satisfying answers.

```
return_value = MsiGetProperty(msihandle, _T("CLIENTPROCESSID"), msiPID, &size);
```

I would expect the process ID of msi process to be present within the msiPID but the string doesn't have any value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't include quite enough to be certain about this, but I suspect your custom action is deferred, and thus CLIENTPROCESSID is unavailable. Unavailable properties are treated just like any other unset property, and thus are equivalent to an empty string, hence the successful return code with an empty output. Note that [MsiGetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions)...

> Supports a limited set of properties when used with deferred execution custom actions: the CustomActionData property, ProductCode property, and UserSID property.Commit custom actions cannot use the MsiGetProperty function to obtain the ProductCode property. Commit custom actions can use the CustomActionData property to obtain the product code.

Typically one must populate the CustomActionData property (by populating with an immediate action sequenced before the deferred action, a property with the same name as the deferred custom action) for any properties beyond those listed in the excerpt above.